# Why is Settings.bundle causing iTunes to say my iPhone App is not valid?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, itunes, monodevelop

Ok, I have been working on an iPhone App using MonoTouch and MonoDevelop for the last few months.  In this time I have been able to deploy to the app to my phone for debugging/testing purposes and have also been able to compile Adhoc versions for my employers to try out.  This has all worked fine... until this week.

The latest version I sent out will not go into iTunes and fails with the following error:

```
The app "Payload.ipa" could not be added to your iTunes library because it is not a valid app.
```

So basically your generic "something is wrong but I am not going to tell you exactly what" kind of error.

My initial investigations seemed to suggest that the problem may be with the app name containing special characters but as I have not changed the app name for a long time this isn't the problem.  I did add a bundle version to info.plist though however removing this didn't fix the problem.

So then I had a look at the files in the output folder and I noticed that Settings.bundle was now included (I added a file called Config.plist to store some settings used by the app).  In MonoDevelop I changed the options to make it "Content" and "Always copy" as suggested by the guides I was following.  This works perfectly when running the app in the Simulator or on my phone via MonoDevelop.  But when I package the app as a .ipa file iTunes says the app is not valid.  If I remove Settings.bundle iTunes accepts it.

I have read that the "Always copy" option isn't required when setting "Content" but the Settings.bundle file still appears in the output (bin) folder even with the option set to "Do not copy".

I also thought that maybe I had to change the name to Root.plist because that's what the examples use and maybe it's expected to be that.  But again changing the name didn't make a difference.

So I was just wondering if anyone else has run into this problem and how do you solve it?

Comment: Have you tried using http://TestFlightApp.com?  I would recommend using it for beta-testing over iTunes.  If your AdHoc build works on the phone when deployed from MonoDevelop, then it should work the same way in iTunes.

Comment: I haven't tried TestFlight yet but having a look at it now.  I'm not sure how this will solve the problem as previously simply emailing the .ipa file to the people that needed it and getting them to sync via iTunes has worked.  But having said that, it's worth a try.

Comment: Do you have these phones setup in your iOS Provisioning Portal?  An easy way to do it is take each phone and plug it to your Mac and click "Use for Development" in XCode's Organizer.  Another way to do this is to ask them for a number on their phone, but I believe TestFlight automates that process for you.

Comment: Yeah, all that has been set up and has been working.  I had also thought that maybe the provisioning profile had expired but it is still valid and from memory that usually gives me a different error.  I have given TestFlight a go and it definitely looks like the way to go for test deployment.  As described above (and below) Settings.bundle is causing the problem.  Getting rid of that file from the Payload folder makes the app work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more mucking around I used TestFlight to deploy the app to my phone (I am not able to sync using iTunes on my development machine).

Deploying the app with the Settings.bundle included in the Payload would not install on the phone even using TestFlight.  However I decided to try without that file to see if the app would work without it and to my surprise it does.

This is a little annoying as previously just copying all the files from the output directory to the Payload directory has worked fine.  I am still not sure why there is a problem when Settings.bundle is present or even why it is there if it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and after hours of investigations I found out that the "settings.bundle"'s resource fork was lost because I was creating/modifying it on a FAT32 partition. You should create the settings.bundle on a OSX partition or repair the resource fork.